# Arcgis android, not showing the correct coordinates

Tags: android, arcgis

I am new to arcgis, and I would like to do a simple thing, yet I can't understand why it does not behave as expected. I am trying to add a point on my mapView. It is added, but in the wrong place.

```
// I have longitude and latitude saved as strings
// x = 53.230
// y = 20.398
Point result = new Point(Float.parseFloat(x),Float.parseFloat(y));

  Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(Double.parseDouble(x), Double.parseDouble(y), SpatialReference.create(4326));

      Geometry resultLocGeom = mapPoint; 
      Geometry resultLocGeom = result; // using mapPoint or result, both gets placed in same place.

  SimpleMarkerSymbol resultSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
    Color.BLACK, 20, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CROSS);

  Graphic resultLocation = new Graphic(resultLocGeom,
    resultSymbol);

  locationLayer.addGraphic(resultLocation);

  TextSymbol resultAddress = new TextSymbol(12, list2.get(i)[3], Color.BLACK);

  resultAddress.setOffsetX(10);

  resultAddress.setOffsetY(50);

  Graphic resultText = new Graphic(resultLocGeom, resultAddress);

  locationLayer.addGraphic(resultText);
```

I know that latitude and longitude are both correct, but my point gets shown somewhere in the Atlantic for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on WGS84 and you need to use Web Mercator.

Here is a similar post online.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/53852-FeatureLayer-does-not-accept-WGS84-(-WKID-4326-)

```
fs=FeatureSet

[PHP]                 
$.each( fs.features, function(k, v){
    point=new esri.geometry.Point( v.geometry.x, v.geometry.y, new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
    point_merc = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(point);

    v.geometry.x=point_merc.x;
    v.geometry.y=point_merc.y;                   
});
[/PHP]
```

Comment: No problem. I used to get that errorall the time with Manifold and ArcGIS.

Comment: this is link not working.please tell solution how to convert me i have also same problem